# Problem printing from ReportViewer control in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, sql, reportviewer, report

I have a web application that utilizes the ReportViewer control in ASP.NET. The reports are defined in the web application, in .rdlc files. 
The reports work great, except for the printing functionality. When the user clicks the "print" icon in the header section of the report, it appears that the web app tries to install SQL Server (?!). Here is the file download dialog that appears:
[image]

Can anyone offer a guess as to what is going on? I am not sure where to even begin to debug this, cause this is all happening "behind the scenes" in the ReportViewer's code.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not SQL Server it's trying to install, its an activex/plugin to print report files, click yes, install this and try to print.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually get the same results no matter what I do, install, don't install or even just pause for a moment when the dialog is displayed...they all crash the tab in the browser, and the site disappears, then the browser "recovers" a blank tab. This is in IE which has to be the browser I use (per the client)

Comment: Try this: 
Go to Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin, and copy these files to Windows\Downloaded Program Files (use command windows, cmd): 
- RSClientPrint.dll
- rsclientprint.inf 
- RsClientPrint_1028.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1031.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1033.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1036.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1040.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1041.rll 
- RsClientPrint_1042.rll 
- RsClientPrint_2052.rll 
- RsClientPrint_3082.rll 
Then, Register RSClientPrint.dll (regsvr32 [path]RSClientPrint.dll). If you can't find these files there, extract rsclientprint.cab.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this. I still get an error...this time, I chose to install the ActiveX thing. It had a problem, asked me if I wanted to debug the issue (using the debugger), I selected no, and it crashed the browser (tab) the same way it did before. I think I should just disable printing on the reports. My clients probably won't be able to download the ActiveX control to get printing. Thank you for your help. I will tell them to export to excel first (or PDF), then print. THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR GUIDANCE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Before i was tried the same problem. But after that i got the solution. The main thing is, we cant print the report directly from the client machine. I have found two way to print the report in client machine. One is through the ActiveX control. The client dont know, how to install the ActiveX Control in their machine, mainly they dont want those irretating things. So i found the other way we can print through the PDF file. Now all are having adobe pdf reader in their machine. So i browsed, how to print directly pdf without saving in their client machine. Finally i got the solution. The steps are:

The sample code written in C#.

**i). Convert Report to Memory Stream:**

```
string reportType = "PDF";
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;
    //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
    ////http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx 

    string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" + "  <PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth>" + "  <PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight>" + "  <MarginTop>0in</MarginTop>" + "  <MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft>" + "  <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>" + "  <MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom>" + "</DeviceInfo>";
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes;
    //Render the report       
    renderedBytes = _rptViewer.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
    Stream mystream = new MemoryStream(renderedBytes);
```